# Why is speech recognition using OOP not working in this case?

Tags: python, speech-recognition

I am trying to use speech recognition with OOP. I try to convert the procedural code from [this github](https://github.com/bradtraversy/alexis_speech_assistant).

```
import speech_recognition as sr #recognise speech
import time


class SpeechRecognition():
    def __init__(self):
        self.r = sr.Recognizer() #initialize recognizer that is responsible for recognizing the speech
            
    # listen for audio and convert it to text:
    def record_audio(self, ask=False):
        with sr.Microphone() as source: # microphone as source
            if ask: 
                print(ask)
            audio = self.r.listen(source) # listen for the audio via source
            voice_data = ''
            try:
                voice_data = self.r.recognize_google(audio, language='sv-SE') # convert audio to text
            except sr.UnknownValueError: # error: recognizer does not understand
                print('Hörde inte det') 
            except sr.RequestError: # error: recognizer is not connected
                print('Ledsen, tjänsten är nere')
            print(f">> {voice_data.lower()}") # print what user said
            return voice_data.lower()

    def init_speech_recognizer(self):
        time.sleep(1)
        print('Hur kan jag hjälpa dig?')

        while 1: #this will let it keep listen 
            voice_data = self.record_audio("Recording") # get the voice input
            print("Done")
            
speechObj = SpeechRecognition()
speechObj.init_speech_recognizer()
```

The output is:

```
Hur kan jag hjälpa dig?
Recording
```

But whatever I say nothing gets printed. Why is this?

Comment: How do you terminate the while loop?

Comment: I do not. I would like it to keep listen. I have also tried using `speechObj.record_audio("Recording")` instead of `speechObj.init_speech_recognizer()`

Comment: The while loop in `init_speech_recognizer` doesnt go forever? You might wanna double check that, also since in your output there is no "Done" printed, that means it gets stuck in `record_audio` Have you tried debugging your code?

Comment: It seems it gets stuck after `audio = self.r.listen(source)`. Do not know why?

Comment: Figured, Does the documentation say when does it stop listenting, bc Im guessing it keeps listening endlessly, which means its either a non defined timer or its waiting for a keyword to stop. Check when does it stop.

Comment: The `listen` method Records a single phrase from source (an AudioSource instance) into an AudioData instance, which it returns.

This is done by waiting until the audio has an energy above `recognizer_instance.energy_threshold` (the user has started speaking), and then recording until it encounters `recognizer_instance.pause_threshold` seconds of non-speaking or there is no more audio input. The ending silence is not included.

Comment: The timeout parameter is the maximum number of seconds that this will wait for a phrase to start before giving up and throwing an `speech_recognition.WaitTimeoutError` exception. If timeout is None, there will be no wait timeout. I have tried to set it to `audio = sr.Recognizer().listen(source, timeout=3)` but no change

Comment: Then perhaps the timeout is never triggered, meaning the energy level will always be above the threshold, could be a result of background noise constantly "producing sound".

Comment: This might be true, there is a loud continuous background noise right know from a car :)

Comment: Try applying a filter to the captured audio before putting it through a speech recognition, or figure a way to remove background noise.